# how can i backup wifi profiles without root?

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, 5.0-lollipop, backup, huawei

this option isn't available in my default backup app ( huawei backup )
android 5.1

that's what Available in the default  backup app 
[image]

[image][image]

note: the managers category doesn't contain any wifi info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your backup app doesn't have such a category, then you cannot back it up. Even in cases where it is synced to your Google account (via the Settings > Google > Backup option) , it is restored only to the phone when you restore the backup while setting up as a new phone. But that will not show you the raw credentials if you're looking to use them. Do note that Google 's backup has its own flaws and this restore may not always work. 
If you need the raw credentials, then you will need to ask the owner of that WiFi network.

Comment: thanks 
although i thought there would be a way around this cause one of my cousins 

have the option of backuping wifi profiles 
..
then he can view the with an sql viewr (.db) without root


i think this was possible only after he installed an old version of the backup 

manger as i think !